# SQL that returns a standard date based on time of year

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

How do I return **July 1**, current year when the current date is after **July 1** current year and return **July 1,** prior year when the current date is before **July 1 current year**?

I have written this in my query but I keep getting this error:

> "Implicit conversion from data type datetime to int is not allowed.
>   Use the CONVERT function to run this query."

Here my sql query:

```
CASE WHEN GETDATE() >= 
(DATETIME2FROMPARTS (year(GETDATE()), 07, 01, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
    THEN (DATETIME2FROMPARTS (DATEADD(year, 0, GETDATE()), 07, 01, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)) 
    ELSE  (DATETIME2FROMPARTS (DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE()), 07, 01, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
    END AS EntryDate,
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You said you want to return July 1 in both cases, so why the need for two cases?

Comment: Sorry, I had formatted my question using carats incorrectly

Comment: I understand now. I don't have SQL running right now (so I can't test this, and I won't answer your question) but maybe you can find something similar [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/04/09/sql-server-fix-error-217-implicit-conversion-from-data-type-datetime-to-int-is-not-allowed-use-the-convert-function-to-run-this-query/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me assume you mean on or after July 1.  Perhaps this does what you want:

```
(case when month(getdate()) >= 7
      then DATETIME2FROMPARTS(year(GETDATE() + 1, 07, 01, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
      else DATETIME2FROMPARTS(year(GETDATE(), 07, 01, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
 end)
```

Comment: I think this would work, but I don't think it would return the right value. You're saying that if we are in july or later, return next year (this year + 1) and if it's not, return this year. I think you want `then` to say `GETDATE()` and `else` to say `GETDATE() - 1`?

Comment: Thank you! I had to switch it around like McAdam331 suggested but this worked perfectly